# WooCommerce stock status in product widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

I have a client who is wanting to display the status of product availability in his future website. We know that you can see the status in the single product page (ie: 5 in stock) and that it's possible to display it in the store archive and category pages. However, I can't find a solution where you can display the stock status in the product widget.

Can this be achieved?

I looked in the content-widget-product.php template and tried adding:

```
<?php echo wp_kses_post( $availability ); ?>
```

**But it didn't work.**

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Find below the WooCommerce source code for the template **`content-widget-product.php`** *(product widget)* with some customization at the end, to get stock Status:

```
<?php
/**
 * ... / ...
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
global $product; ?>

<li>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $product->get_permalink() ); ?>">
        <?php echo $product->get_image(); ?>
        <span class="product-title"><?php echo $product->get_name(); ?></span>
    </a>
    <?php if ( ! empty( $show_rating ) ) : ?>
        <?php echo wc_get_rating_html( $product->get_average_rating() ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
    <?php 
        // Compatibility for WC versions from 2.5.x to 3.0+
        if ( method_exists( $product, 'get_stock_status' ) ) {
            $stock_status = $product->get_stock_status(); // For version 3.0+
        } else {
            $stock_status = $product->stock_status; // Older than version 3.0
        }
        echo ' '.$stock_status;
    ?>
</li>
```

*(This code is compatible from WooCommerce version 2.5.x to 3.0+)*

This code is tested and works.

> You can display the product **Stock quantity** using [**`WC_Product get_stock_quantity()`** method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_stock_quantity).

---

Official documentation: [WC_Product method get_stock_status()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_stock_status)

Answer (score 3):

I have used this in the past to get the stock status:

get_post_meta( $product->ID, '_stock_status', true );